# Reveal div on Opposite Side of Page

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to show a div/imge by hovering over a complete separate div on the opposite side of the page in just html and css? And to add to that, is it possible to show multiple images in one div?

I am hoping to create a site that allows you to see the image of a div when you hover over it, but be able see each new image in the same place. I hope I was clear enough and that someone can help me, Thank you.

Comment: I believe you need to use javascript to accomplish this

Answer (score 2):

Here is my suggestion: You can use a CSS sibling selector to access the hidden DIV. Here is quick example that I've made:

CSS (with a bit of styling) and HTML (with dummy paragraphs to demonstrate the other elements on your page plus I've placed multiple images in the hidden DIV, since you asked if it's possible to show multiple images in one DIV):

```css
.first {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  right: 100px;
  bottom: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.second {
  display: none;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.first:hover ~ .second {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">HOVER ME</div>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
<div class="second">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="Dummy Image #1">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="Dummy Image #1">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="Dummy Image #1">
</div>
```